# How to pass struct array arguments to a function the right way?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct

**Source Code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Employee {

   string name;
   int age;
   float salary;

};

void displayData(Employee);

int main() {

   Employee employee[3];
   int sizeOfEmployee = sizeof(employee) / sizeof(employee[0]);

   for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfEmployee; i++) {
       cout << "Enter name for employee " << i + 1 << ": ";
       cin >> employee->name;
       cout << "Enter age for employee " << i + 1 << ": ";
       cin >> employee->age;
       cout << "Enter salary for employee " << i + 1 << ": ";
       cin >> employee->salary;       
}

   for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfEmployee; i++) {
       displayData(employee[i]);
}

}

void displayData(Employee employee) {

   cout << "DISPLAYING INFORMATION" << endl;
   cout << "Name: " << employee.name << endl;
   cout << "Age: " << employee.age << endl;
   cout << "Salary: " << employee.salary << endl;

}
```

**My code doesn't display all the data i've stored into the array, it only reads and display the last data i've inputted.**

**CODE OUTPUT:**

[image: CODE OUTPUT:]

**In what way could i possibly get all the data i've stored into the array and display it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading data into a pointer to the first element of the array. To read into n-th element your code should be using indexing, like `cin >> employee[i].name;`.

However...

"Naked" arrays are a source of many errors, subtle bugs, and generally unsafe code. Consider using `std::array` instead - this will eliminate the need for code like `int sizeOfEmployee = sizeof(...` and will nicely encapsulate that array as a parameter to a function:

```
#include <array>

int main() {

   std::array<Employee, 3> employee;

   for(int i = 0; i < employee.size(); i++) {
       cout << "Enter name for employee " << i + 1 << ": ";
       cin >> employee[i].name;
   // the rest of that for loop...
   }
// and the second loop becomes:
   for(const auto& e: employee) {
       displayData(e);
}
```

Comment: actually you can use range based for on array as well.

Comment: A range-based loop can be used for the input, as well: `int i = 1; for(auto &e : employee) { cout << "Enter name for employee " << i << ": "; cin >> e.name; ... ++i; }`

Comment: Both comments are valid, I was just trying to provide "gentle introduction" into range-based loops :)

Comment: It took me a long period of time to understand this solution you've provided me which is my bad and it easily solved my problem without adding more complexity, Thank you so much for this .

Answer (score 2):

You are reading data 3 times into the first element in your array:

```cpp
Employee employee[3];

for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfEmployee; i++) {
    cout << "Enter name for employee " << i + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> employee->name; // employee points to the first element in the array
}
```

One more comment: your are passing the `Employee` class by value just to display it. It would be mych better, efficient and robust to pass it by const reference:

```cpp
void displayData(const Employee&);
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained how to solve the 1st issue.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int sizeOfEmployee = sizeof(employee) / sizeof(employee[0]);
> ```

Don't do this. Use `std::size(employee)` if you want to get the length of the array.

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfEmployee; i++) {
> ```

Don't do this. Instead, use a range-for to loop over all elements of a range:

```
for (auto&& e : employee)
```

Which incidentally will fix the bug that you had. The bug is that you always write to the first element of the array. Each iteration over-writes the previous ones and the other elements remain uninitialised.

The range-for will correctly iterate all elements with less chance of messing things up.

Comment: @RemyLebeau lvalue reference would be ok here, but there are subtle cases where it would be wrong, such as those where range returns reference wrappers. Forwarding reference is more robust.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to input a variable number of employees, then you should use the STL
container `std::vector`. Please have a look at its
[documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Below you find the usage of `std::vector` for your given code as well as some
hints starting with the label `//CKE:`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> //CKE: Very powerful STL container for arrays

using namespace std;

struct Employee {
   string name;
   int age = INT_MIN; //CKE: Always initialize variables in C++
   float salary = 0.; //CKE: Always initialize variables in C++
};

void displayData(const Employee&); //CKE: Use const reference if possible

int main() {

   vector<Employee> employees; //CKE: Declaration of dynamic array in C++
   size_t counter = 0;         //CKE: Counts number of given data sets
   string addOneMore;          //CKE: Holds check for more input data
   do {
       ++counter;
       Employee employee;
      cout << "Enter name for employee " << counter << ": ";
      cin >> employee.name;
      cout << "Enter age for employee " << counter << ": ";
      cin >> employee.age;
      cout << "Enter salary for employee " << counter << ": ";
      cin >> employee.salary;
      employees.push_back(employee); //CKE: Save data in dynamic array
      cout << "Want to add another employee? (y/n): ";
      cin >> addOneMore;
   } while (addOneMore == "y");

   for (const auto& employee : employees) { //CKE: Use range base loop for output
      displayData(employee);
   }
   return 0; //CKE: Always return an integer in int main function of C++
}

void displayData(const Employee& employee) { //CKE: No copying of struct Employee
   cout << "DISPLAYING INFORMATION" << endl;
   cout << "Name: " << employee.name << endl;
   cout << "Age: " << employee.age << endl;
   cout << "Salary: " << employee.salary << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply fixed my problem by using loop counter:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Employee {

   string name;
   int age;
   float salary;

};

void displayData(Employee[], int);

int main() {

   Employee employee[3];
   int sizeOfEmployee = sizeof(employee) / sizeof(employee[0]);

   for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfEmployee; i++) {
       cout << "Enter name for employee " << i + 1 << ": ";
       getline(cin, employee[i].name);
       cout << "Enter age for employee " << i + 1 << ": ";
       cin >> employee[i].age;
       cout << "Enter salary for employee " << i + 1 << ": ";
       cin >> employee[i].salary;     
       cin.ignore();  
   }

   displayData(employee, sizeOfEmployee);


}

void displayData(Employee employee[], int sizeOfEmployee) {

   cout << "DISPLAYING INFORMATION" << endl;

   for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfEmployee; i++) {
       cout << "Name: " << employee[i].name << endl;
       cout << "Age: " << employee[i].age << endl;
       cout << "Salary: " << employee[i].salary << endl;
   }

}
```

Thanks to all the people who helped me and provided me with answers. Very much appreciated as I'm still learning :))